# Optimising a query to get rows where x is between pairs of values from another table

Tags: postgresql, performance, optimization, postgresql-9.4, query-performance

PostgreSQL 9.4.5

In my database there are 2 tables, **vcfentries** and **exons**.

I want to query for rows in vcfentries where *pos* is between a list of pairs of positions, exonstart and exonend in the table exons.

Result of the query:
select * from exons where exons.genename = 'NM_001301824'

[image: exons table]

Total query runtime: 11 ms.
8 rows retrieved.

This is the equivalent of pulling up the results for a single exon without any joins across tables:

```
Select pos,chrom,alt,ref from vcfentries 
where chrom = '1' 
and pos > 33546679  
and pos < 33547159
```

Total query runtime: 11 ms.
89 rows retrieved.

Currently these are the indexes I have on the tables

[image: Table indexes]
[image: Table indexes]

Querying for a specific exon is efficient:

```
select vcfentries.pos,vcfentries.chrom,vcfentries.alt,vcfentries.ref,exons.exonnumber from exons , vcfentries
where vcfentries.pos BETWEEN  exons.exonstart
and exons.exonend
and exons.genename = 'NM_001301824'
and exonnumber = 6
and vcfentries.chrom = exons.chrom
```

Total query runtime: 72 ms.
137 rows retrieved.

```
"Nested Loop  (cost=438468.31..2324377.64 rows=809587 width=24)"
"  ->  Index Only Scan using exonspkey on exons  (cost=0.42..8.44 rows=1 width=26)"
"        Index Cond: ((genename = 'NM_001301824'::text) AND (exonnumber = 8))"
"  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on vcfentries  (cost=438467.89..2317823.87 rows=654532 width=16)"
"        Recheck Cond: ((pos >= exons.exonstart) AND (pos <= exons.exonend) AND (chrom = exons.chrom))"
"        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on vcfentries_pos_chrom_idx  (cost=0.00..438304.26 rows=654532 width=0)"
"              Index Cond: ((pos >= exons.exonstart) AND (pos <= exons.exonend) AND (chrom = exons.chrom))"
```

The performance goes down the toilet when querying for them all. Suddenly it jumps into the minutes range:

```
select * from exons , vcfentries
where vcfentries.pos BETWEEN  exons.exonstart
and exons.exonend
and exons.genename = 'NM_001037501'
and vcfentries.chrom = exons.chrom
```

Total query runtime: 325389 ms.
2331 rows retrieved.

```
"Hash Join  (cost=58.73..11528494.14 rows=11334216 width=24)"
"  Output: vcfentries.pos, vcfentries.chrom, vcfentries.alt, vcfentries.ref, exons.exonnumber"
"  Hash Cond: (vcfentries.chrom = exons.chrom)"
"  Join Filter: ((vcfentries.pos >= exons.exonstart) AND (vcfentries.pos <= exons.exonend))"
"  ->  Seq Scan on coeus.vcfentries  (cost=0.00..7170736.76 rows=141378976 width=16)"
"        Output: vcfentries.pos, vcfentries.chrom, vcfentries.alt, vcfentries.ref, vcfentries.analysisid, vcfentries.filter, vcfentries.info_ac, vcfentries.info_af, vcfentries.info_an, vcfentries.info_baseqranksum, vcfentries.info_clippingranksum, vcfentrie (...)"
"  ->  Hash  (cost=58.56..58.56 rows=14 width=26)"
"        Output: exons.exonnumber, exons.exonstart, exons.exonend, exons.chrom"
"        ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on coeus.exons  (cost=4.53..58.56 rows=14 width=26)"
"              Output: exons.exonnumber, exons.exonstart, exons.exonend, exons.chrom"
"              Recheck Cond: (exons.genename = 'NM_001301824'::text)"
"              ->  Bitmap Index Scan on exons_genename_idx  (cost=0.00..4.53 rows=14 width=0)"
"                    Index Cond: (exons.genename = 'NM_001301824'::text)"
```

The exons table is modest in size with only about 400K rows.

The vcfentries table is large with a few hundred million rows but is acceptably fast to query with indexes.

I'm having trouble optimizing this query. When I run explain on my attempts to use explicit joins I get the same execution plan.

Any ideas why it's creating such a bad execution plan and any suggested fixes or better queries?

Comment: Do you have an index on `(chrom, pos)`?

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ On the vcfentries table I do. Do you think a combined index across exonstart,exonend and chrom in the exons table might help?

Comment: Are you sure? I see indexes starting with `(pos, chrom)` but not with `(chrom, pos)`.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ you're right, I didn't think about index order. I'll add it and see if it improves performance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution I implemented for this was to add a plpgsql function which ran each individual query and output the results as a table.

I defined an output record type and used this function:

```
DROP FUNCTION coeus.getexonvcf(text);
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION coeus.getexonvcf(text) RETURNS SETOF coeus.exonvcf AS
$BODY$
DECLARE
    r bigint;
    s coeus.exonvcf;
BEGIN
    FOR r IN SELECT exonnumber FROM coeus.exons where exons.genename = $1
    LOOP
        for s IN select ex.genename,ex.exonnumber,ex.direction,ex.padding, vcf.* from coeus.exons ex, coeus.vcfentries vcf
        where vcf.pos BETWEEN  ex.exonstart and ex.exonend
        and ex.genename = $1
        and ex.exonnumber = r
        and vcf.chrom = ex.chrom
        LOOP
            RETURN NEXT s;
        END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
    RETURN;
END
$BODY$
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' ;
```

This avoids any full table scans and runs in slightly over a second.

Total query runtime: 1493 ms.
2331 rows retrieved.

For genes with very large numbers of exon entries like Titin (363) it's slow but in the average case it's acceptably fast.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest using a CTE in this instance. Something that looks like this:

```
with exons (genename, exonnumber, crom, exonstart, exonend, padding, direction) as
    (select genename, exonnumber, crom, exonstart, exonend, padding, direction
     from exons
     where enename = 'NM_001037501')
select *
from vcfentries vcf
join exons exo
using (chrom)
where vcf.pos between exo.exonstart and exo.exonend;
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but unfortunately it looks to be taking about equally long to run.  Total query runtime: 372740 ms.